# Why application hitting on-prem ADFS as well?

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms application. It was using on-prem ADFS for SSO. Recently I modified it to use Azure AD and modified the web.config.

In the web.config, I modified the below strings:

```
<add key="ida:ADFSMetadata">
<add key="ida:Wtrealm">
<add key="ida:ADFSDiscoveryDoc">
```

The Azure AD MetaData URL starts with https://login.microsoftonline.com whereas the on-prem ADFS was something like this: https://adfs.abc.com

Now when I execute the application, it hits Azure AD and later on-prem ADFS as well and opens the application. I am not understanding why it goes to on-prem ADFS when in the web.config there is no declaration of on-prem ADFS?

Someone pointed out that it may be due to Azure AD being configured that way. Any hybrid model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that your org's AAD is configured to login with federation through your on-premise ADFS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-whatis